# How to declare a custom class relation in OWL2

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

My apologies if my question is too basic, but after some time looking for an answer, I had nowhere to go but here.

Suppose the following classes in an ontology (expressed in an OWL 2 file):

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="ClasseOne">
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:ID="ClasseTwo">
</owl:Class>
```

What I have is 1000 instances of `ClassOne` and 5000 instances of `ClassTwo`. In my reality *all* the `ClassOne` instances are related in the very same way (let's say the relationship is named "isRelatedTo") to *all* the instances of `ClassTwo`.

My idea was to declare a class relation and use it in the declaration of `ClassOne`, instead of having an ObjectProperty that should have its value declared in each `ClassOne` instance.

How to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A Relation in Ontology should be expressed using object property.

Comment: Relations in an Ontology describe the way in which individuals relate to each other. Relations can normally be expressed directly between individuals (this article has author Phillip Lord) or between Concepts (an article has author a person); in the latter case, this describes a relationship between all individuals of the Concepts.

Comment: @M.Sarmini: Thanks for your reply. Yes, that was my understanding too, but can you imagine having 1000 individuals that have 5000 ObjectProperties each? That's what will happen if I have to relate each instance of `ClassOne` to the other 5000 instances of `ClassTwo`. What I'm looking for is a way to relate classes, so all the individuals will implicitly share those relations, just like what happens with, for instance, `rdfs:subClassOf`. So, what you are telling is: there is no way to accomplish what I want. Is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are not related by properties in OWL except for subsumption/equivalence. Usually, individuals of a class `A` are related to individuals of a class `B` by a property `p`, e.g. `A(a1), B(b1), p(a1, b1)` states that an individual `a1` of class `A` is related by `p` to an individual `b1` of class `B`.

You could express something like any individual of A has a relationship `p` to an individual of B by using a subclass axiom with an OWL class expression as super class, e.g.

`Class: A
  SubClassOf: p some B`

(in Manchester OWL Syntax here)

Note, that this doesn't necessary mean the other way around, i.e. the direction matters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, what you described above is that all instances of `A` (a1, a2, a3, ...) are implicitly related to all instances of `B` (b1, b2, b3, ...). is that right?Is `p` an `ObjectProperty`?

Comment: So, `p some B` works here as an annonymous class. Is that right? What if I need the same behavior to other classes? Like all individuals of `A` are implicitly related to all individuals of `B`, `C`, and `D`? Can I have a multiple inheritance here?

Comment: @AlexSC Yes, p is an object property in my example. Yes it is an anonymous class. Yes, you could add multiple subclass statements or use an intersection `(p some B) and (s some C) and ...`